# Can't Install Ubuntu 12.10 on Asus X401U help needed

Tags: asus, sata, installation

I have a SATA with 320gb running Windows 8 I am trying to dual boot.

I tried Installing It through a USB but received this message. Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda2' failed. I tried using the original sda but I can't add to it.
I have 82Gb ready for Ubuntu but every attempt to install it has failed.
I have also tried installing it with the windows installer on the Ubuntu website but nothing works.Here is what the partitions look like, https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhTSi.jpg 
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/bY3J3.jpg

Any help would be appreciated if im being vague ask and I will try to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should install grub to the MBR. So just let Ubuntu install grub automatically to /dev/sda. You do not want it installed to /dev/sda1 or /dev/sda2.
There is no need to add anything to the original /dev/sda, as you said you tried to do.

Comment: MBR please explain? I am pretty noobish I did a USB install just automatically but that didn't work either.